# Tools to JVM/AS monitoring

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, websphere

I'm researching about the tools that are helpful to monitoring the JVM(memory, processor, number of threads) and/or the use of Application Server resources during the application production (requests, number of the EJBs in the pool etc etc).

I know only the jconsole and the VisualVM

What else Do you know? For what purpose do you use?

Thanks a lot =]

---

Thanks for the answers until now. Does someone know some tool to monitoring WebLogic?

Answer (score 2):

Try JavaMelody also.

https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/

Answer (score 1):

jhat - to get memory dump on server

jstack - to get traces for all current threads and see if there are deadlocks

jmap - for heap summary view

jstat - performance stats

those tools are console-based and easy to use on servers without GUI

Answer (score 0):

WAS ISC has built-in PMI (Performance Monitoring Infrastructure) - it allows to collect all performance data per server that you mentioned.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer but, I couldn't find this tool "WAS ISC" in the google. :S  Can you give me a link please? Sorry if a didn't understand so good.

Comment: ISC stands for Integrated Solutions Console. Widely used name is WebSphere admin console (the web based administration tool). Check the Info center - http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Ftprf_monitoringhealth.html.

Comment: Also look out for Health Center that should be part of IBM JDKs

Answer (score 0):

You can check RHQ Platform. It allows you to manage and monitor not only JVM  but also many other services. These solution is especially useful when you use some JBoss server.

But it also quite complicates and better suited for production environment.

Here is link: http://www.jboss.org/rhq

Answer (score 0):

The official tool of IBM for Websphere Monitoring is the **IBM Tivoli Composite Application Manager for Application Diagnostics (ITCAM for AD)** which together with **IBM Tivoli Monitoring (ITM)** Platform gives you a complete picture of what is happing in your production server along with alerts, historical data, some actions when an event happens etc.

Alternatively you may try solutions such as Health Center provided with [Support Assistant](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/support/isa) or use an open source monitoring system such as Nagios and use plugins that can monitor the Websphere environment.

If you just want to troubleshoot a problem quickly and not need a full monitoring product with alerts, historical data etc you may just use the **Performance Viewer** app (located in Monitoring and Tuning > Performance Viewer > Current Activity from Admin Console) to get all the metrics you mentioned.